# Why is a path overflowing in a TikZ picture

Tags: tikz-pgf

In the following path, there is a small overflowing of the stroke `(1,1) --++(0,-1)` beyond the stroke `(0,0)--++(2,0)`. It seems to be because I use a path in my second expression and that the following stroke is sideways. Why is it ? How can I prevent it while still using a path for the strokes.

```
\draw (0,0)--++(2,0);
\draw (1,1) --++(0,-1)--++(0.5,0.5)--++(0,-0.5);
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Can you please give us a complete [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The "overflowing" is caused by the type of `line join`:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \join [count=\x] in {round, bevel, miter}{
\begin{scope}[shift=(0:\x*3), line width=.25cm, line join=\join]
\draw [opacity=0.5] (0,2) -- (2,0);
\draw [opacity=0.5] (0,0) -- (1,1) -- (1,0);
\node at (1,-1) {\join};
\end{scope}
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You can also change the `miter limit` which is the multiple of line widths beyond which the `miter` line join will be replaced by a `bevel` line join.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \m [count=\x] in {0,10}{
\begin{scope}[shift=(0:\x*3), line width=.25cm, line join=miter, miter limit=\m]
\draw [opacity=0.5] (0,2) -- (2,0);
\draw [opacity=0.5] (0,0) -- (1,1) -- (1,0);
\node at (1,-1) {miter limit: \m};
\end{scope}
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

These parameters can be set at the level of the `tikzpicture`, `scope` or individual path.